# StackOverflowException after rendering view to client

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm just learning MVC so apologies if this is a newbie mistake, but I couldn't find the solution anywhere else.

I'm attempting to create a page where multiple records can be edited. In debug mode my view will render and display in my browser, but then I get a StackOverflowException in the System.Web.dll. If I publish the code to my production server the HTTP request never completes (times out).

This is MVC5 with EntityFramework 6.1.

Here's the controller's action method:

```
' GET: HonorBoxes
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim hb = From h In db.honorBoxes Select h Where Not h.Filled And Not h.Hold
    Return View(hb.ToList())
End Function
```

And the view:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of Vending.HonorBox)
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.BeginForm("Index", "HonorBoxes")
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.BoxID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Qty)
        </th>
    </tr>

@For x = 0 To Model.Count - 1
    @code 
        Dim item As HonorBox = Model(x)
    End Code
    @<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Display(item.BoxID)
            @Html.Hidden("boxes(" & x & ").BoxID", item.BoxID)
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox("boxes(" & x & ").Qty", item.Qty)

        </td>
    </tr>
Next

</table>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, the model class in question (in case it is relevant):

```
Public Class HonorBox
    Private _filled As Nullable(Of Boolean)
    Private _qty As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Private _hold As Nullable(Of Boolean)


    <Key> Public Property BoxID As Integer
    Public Property AssetID As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property Asset As Asset
    Public Property BoxType As String
    Public Property Hold As Nullable(Of Boolean)
        Get
            If IsDBNull(_hold) Then Return False
            Return _hold
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Boolean))
            _hold = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Filled As Nullable(Of Boolean)
        Get
            If IsDBNull(_filled) Then Return False
            Return _filled
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Boolean))
            _filled = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Qty As Nullable(Of Integer)
        Get
            If IsDBNull(_qty) Then Return 0
            Return _qty
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Integer))
            _qty = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

EDIT - So the exception is thrown from the Serialization library sometimes. This caused me to wonder if it was the number of records I was attempting to edit that was causing the StackOverflowException. I reduced the number of records displayed and sure enough it works fine. I'm not sure what is causing this however - I'd still like to edit more records at a time if possible.

EDIT #2 (ADDED VIEWMODEL) - I was unaware of viewmodels until they were mentioned below. I added an HonorBoxView model to the project (with only .Qty and .BoxID properties), changed the model-type in the View, and modified the Controller methods to the following:

```
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim hb = From h In db.honorBoxes Select h Where Not h.Filled And Not h.Hold
        Dim hbv As IEnumerable(Of HonorBoxView) = From h In hb Select New HonorBoxView() With {.Qty = h.Qty, .BoxID = h.BoxID}
        Return View(hbv.ToList())
    End Function

    <HttpPost>
    Function Index(boxes As List(Of HonorBoxView)) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            For Each box In boxes
                Dim cbox = db.honorBoxes.Find(box.BoxID)
                If Not IsDBNull(box.Qty) AndAlso cbox.Qty <> box.Qty Then
                    cbox.Qty = box.Qty
                    cbox.Filled = True
                End If
            Next
            db.SaveChanges()
        End If
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End Function
```

I'm still getting the same StackOverflowException. It happens after the HTML is rendered to the client but before the request completes.

Comment: How many records are you trying to display?

Comment: I was initially trying it with 200 and was getting the exception. I reduced it to 50 and it worked ok.

Comment: If the `Asset` property is complex you may need to be more selective about what you try to handle in one view -- Either with a simplified HonorBoxViewModel or paginate the set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added a slimmed down viewmodel but am still getting the same exception thrown after the HTML is rendered.

Comment: Just a guess but have you properly closed all of your `<td>` tags or is that just a typo?

Comment: Good catch - and strangely, that was it. No more StackOverflowException. Thank you!